# Database Integration with Excel (do not have MS Access)

Tags: excel, database

I am trying to design a calculator template to figure pricing for waterjet cutting.  I have excel but no MS Access or other DB program.  I can do this using simple formulas in an excel spreadsheet but I would like to link it to a couple of different databases (one is my customer database and the other is my master material database).  This way I can enter the customer #, have the account information populate automatically and subsequently do the same for my material database which has all my thicknesses, grades, weight/SF etc.  I've been reading about how to utilize Power Pivot to link database short of having MS Access or a standalone DB program, but not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree for what I'm trying to do or not. I've attached a model of what I want the output to look like but just need to know if there is a way to link the databases solely through excel.

Waterjet pricing calculator:

[image: Waterjet pricing calculator]

Comment: Does this system need to write back to any database? Or do you just want to have something that sucks out data and applies excel calcs to it? It's pretty easy to write VBA to suck data out and put it in specific cells in excel. What kind of databases are these external DB'sm and how do you authenticate to them?

Comment: Thanks for the input Nick.  I have never really explored VBA at all but I'll see if I can answer your questions as best I can.  These external databases are simply an export of both an account file and headings or inventory file from Filemaker 6. FM 6 is where the original calculator was done and support it at this point is waning to say the least.  Basically I'm just looking to have selected fields (customer name - from Acct # and product description & weight per SF - from the inventory item #) populate in some sort of spreadsheet with excel calcs embedded in it. Thank you again!

Comment: So are you reading directly from filemaker or are you reading from files that have been exported from filemaker? Have you thought about a longer term solution to replacing the whole fm6 system before it keels over?

Comment: You should be able to build all of what you want in Excel, but anything complex in Excel can be buggy and catankerous. So basically your inputs are a customer number and one(?) material. After you enter those, all the attributes come through, then you enter some other stuff and it should do some calcs?

Comment: First step is to continue with Power Query (yes) and import those two datasets into two different tabs. You want to build this so that it's easy to get any updated data in those into an excel tab. You should also actually be able to connect to FM6 via ODBC directly and skip and file export step. Once you've done that you just need to implement the two lookups (client and material), then all the other stuff should just be excel formulas.

Comment: We actually have moved on from FM6.  We moved all the way through FM13 and have since changed over to Metal Centric (basically a canned order entry system for the metals industry) but all of the custom/additional programming is being done outside. This calc template was done many moons ago in FM6 and I'm just fishing for an similar solution independent of FM or SQL/database integration. I think I've created the two data sets as tabs within Power Pivot but once I create the calc template with all the necessary fields I'm just not sure how to implement the lookups.

Comment: I'm probably a bit over my skis here as I have very little exposure to much of this.  What you're saying is making sense to me I just need to dig a bit deeper to try to tie it all in together.  I've played around a bit with trying to learn some Objective C and a very little bit of Python because I love to tinker with this stuff but have never done it formally or gone in depth enough to be very proficient with it.  I think I'm on the right track to a simplistic solution - just need to keep digging. I really appreciate you taking the time to offer me some guidance.

Comment: For this purpose I suggest you drop Objective C and Python and look into VBA. This link seems like a straightforward way to get you started. If you go up to step 7, this should give you enough knowhow to create the form above, even if it does nothing at this stage. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_userforms.htm